# Best way to practice solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, remix, etherscan

Pardon my question. I'm new on Solidity yet very curious to learn more about the language.
I've done many research on the web, trying to absorb the most I can to understand about the code, and believe me, I'm catching up quite fast. I don't have experience with Java script which makes things a little harder for me to understand how the lines of codes are structured. I do understand some of the variables and functions based on the material I've found on articles and youtube videos, however I'm still struggling to understand what's the best way to structure the lines of solidity codes.

I was wondering if there would be any patter to follow to make it easy to understand, but I wasn't able to find that. The programmers that are on YouTube don't talk about patters that could be followed while writing a function on solidity, and that's what I would like to know.

I'm trying to learn by my own and something not having someone to explain a certain doubt makes it hard to move forward.

Hope somebody here would be able to explain to me if there is any patter that I could follow to write functions on solidity.

Answer (score 0):

Solidity documentation has a [style guide](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/style-guide.html). Other projects like [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/GUIDELINES.md) add a few details.